# Integration Testing with: Best in Place, Capybara & RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, best-in-place

How do I test a `best_in_place` field like this with Capybara and Rspec? I'm new to this.

```
<span 
   class='best_in_place' 
   id='best_in_place_user_233952_name' 
   data-url='/users/233952' 
   data-object='user' 
   data-attribute='name' 
   data-nil='User Name' 
   data-type='textarea' 
   data-original-content=''>
</span>
```

I want to fill in the best in place text area with a name.

Comment: [has_css?](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/1.1.2/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_css%3F-instance_method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

I had to add `config.include BestInPlace::TestHelpers` to my `spec_helper.rb` in order to use the [best in place test helpers](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#test-helpers):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|  
  config.include BestInPlace::TestHelpers 
end
```

And in my test I did this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'create a new user' do 
    scenario "create user Alice", :js => true do
        visit '/some_path'

        click_on 'New User'
        expect(page).to have_content 'User Name' # [1]

        user = User.order(:created_at).last
        bip_area user, :name, 'Alice'

        expect(page).to have_content 'Alice'
    end  
end
```

[1] is important, because it will wait until the JS has loaded the field!

Comment: Thanks for the code example. For anyone else reading this you may need to also add `require 'best_in_place'` & `require 'best_in_place/test_helpers'` to your `spec_helper.rb` file if you haven't done so already

Comment: For me, it was these two lines that needed to be added: `require 'best_in_place/test_helpers'` and
`include BestInPlace::TestHelpers`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have JavaScript enabled:

```
fill_in("best_in_place_user_#{user.id}_name", with: 'some text')
page.execute_script "$('#best_in_place_user_#{user.id}_name').trigger('keyup')"
```

Comment: OK, but how do I get the right id here? Because 233952 is dynamically generated.

Comment: You interpolate the id into the string. Example code updated to show this.

Comment: `"best_in_place_user_#{user.id}_name"` returns the right id, thx! But if I use it in `fill_in`, the test gives me back this error: `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "best_in_place_user_2_name"` (`user.id=2` is the right one, I have checked. And `:js=>true`).

Comment: Are you using the javascript driver? Selenium, phantomjs or similar is needed to make the js run in the first place. If so, then you have the id for the wrong element. Best in place adds an input to type into, so you need to get the id for that. The one above is for the span element which cannot be filled in.